# Create Angular service for dropdown

Tags: java, spring, angular

I want to create a service in order to populate dropdown from database. I tried this:

Merchant Class:

```
export class Merchant {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public state_raw: string,
    public users: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Merchant Service:

```
 getList(): Observable<Merchant> {
    return this.http.get<Merchant>(environment.api.urls.merchants.base, {});
  }
```

Rest Api impl:

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> get() {
        return merchantRepository
                .findAll()
                .map(mapper::toDTO)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
```

SQL query:

```
@Override
    public Iterable<Merchants> findAll() {
        String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
        TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
        List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
        return merchants;
    }
```

I this this erro:

```
The method map(mapper::toDTO) is undefined for the type Iterable<Merchants>
```

How should I implement properly this response?

Comment: Do you want converting to DTO whole collection or each element of collection?

Comment: I want to convert each element.